# Determining $a$ such that adjacent loops in the parameterized curve $(x,y) = (t+a\sin2t, \sin t)$ are tangent

Tags: numerical-methods

Consider the parametric equations of the independent parameter $t$ as follows:

$$\begin{cases} x = t + a \sin(2t) \\
y = \sin(t)\end{cases}$$

- When $a = 0$, we get the usual sine curve.
- When $a = 0.4$ we get a near saw-tooth curve.

[image]

- When $a = 0.5$ the peaks of the curve become cusped
- When $a > 0.5$, loops form.

[image]

- When $a \approx 3.895$ the adjacent loops become tangent.

[image]

- For values of $a > 3.895$ (approx) the loops overlap.

[image]

> Question: Is there a way to calculate this "tangent" value of $a \approx 3.895$ more precisely and analytically, or can it only be found by numerical means?

Comment: Could you clarify what means *"the adjacent loops become tangent"* ? Tangent to what. Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici -= tangent to each other.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not see what you mean (I am probably dumb). Could you add a plot and explain ? Thanks

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - OK - good idea

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - plots added as requested.

Comment: Not likely. This involves solving the [transcendental equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sqrt%284a%5E2-1%29+%2Barccsc%282a%29+%3D+5pi%2F2),$$\sqrt{4a^2-1}+\csc^{-1}(2a)=\frac{5\pi}2$$

Comment: @user170231 - many thanks for this useful result.  Could you please display some of this working/derivation?

Comment: From visual inspection of the graph, when $a \approx 3.895$, the first (smallest positive $x$) self-tangent point is approximately $(4.71, 0.75)$.  That works out to $t \approx 0.85$.  Not sure how much that helps.

Comment: We have (nasty) very accurate approximations

Comment: Much updated (have a look at the edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from @user170231's answer, we are looking for the zero of function
$$f(a)= \csc^{-1}(2a) + \sqrt{4a^2-1}-  \frac{5\pi}2 $$
$$\csc\big(f(a)\big)=\frac{2 a}{\sqrt{4 a^2-1} \sin \left(\sqrt{4 a^2-1}\right)+\cos
   \left(\sqrt{4 a^2-1}\right)}$$ Multiply by the conjugate of the denominator to face the problem of solving for $x$
$$\sin(x)-x\,\cos(x)=0 \qquad \text{with}\qquad x=\sqrt{4a^2-1}$$

The $n^{\text{th}}$ root of $\tan(x)=x$ is well known; it write
$$x_{(n)}=q-\frac 1q \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {\alpha_k}{\beta_k} \frac 1{q^{2k}}\qquad \text{with}\qquad q=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$$ Coefficients $\alpha_k$ and $\beta_k$ form sequences $A079330$ and $A088989$ in $OEIS$.

Because of the $\frac {5\pi}2$, we need to use $n=2$ which means $q=\frac {5\pi}2$  and the solution is then
$$a=\frac 12 \sqrt{1+x^2_{(2)}}$$

Working now the expansion of $a$, we have, the simple
$$a=\frac 12 \Bigg(q-\frac 1q \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {\alpha_k}{\beta_k} \frac 1{q^{2k}}\Bigg)\qquad \text{with}\qquad q=\frac {5\pi}2$$

Vaclav Kotesovec wrote that
$$\frac {\alpha_k}{\beta_k} \propto \frac{\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{2 k}}{k^{4/3}}\qquad \implies \qquad
\frac{\frac {\alpha_{k+1}}{\beta_{k+1}} \frac 1{q^{2(k+1)}}}
{\frac {\alpha_{k}}{\beta_{k}} \frac 1{q^{2k}}}=\frac{1}{25} \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{4/3}$$

So, a fast convergence for the summation. Let $p$ be the level of expansion of $\tan(x)-x$. The results are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & a_{(p)} \\
 1 & 3.89554998993 \\
 2 & 3.89503823412 \\
 3 & 3.89485935285 \\
 4 & 3.89485434524 \\
 5 & 3.89485296250 \\
 6 & 3.89485289919 \\
 7 & 3.89485288482 \\
 8 & 3.89485288394 \\
 9 & 3.89485288376 \\
 10 & 3.89485288375 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Very clever - many thanks!!  That should converge quickly!

Comment: @Dottard. I computed $10,000$ figures without any trouble.

Comment: You have (correctly) focused on the second solution.  But every zero of tan(x) = x gives a significant result for the original question - and provide more tangencies - the odd ones give results corresponding to "anti-tangents" - loops tangent to each other but on opposite sides of the X axis, while the even solution give regular tangents on the same side of the X axis.

Answer (score 2):

The points of tangency occur where the tangent to the curve is vertical, i.e. when

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= 1 + 2a \cos(2t) = 0 \\
\implies t &= \pm \frac12 \cos^{-1}\left(-\frac1{2a}\right) + n\pi \\
&= \pm \left(\frac12 \csc^{-1}(2a) + \frac\pi4\right) + n\pi \\
\end{align*}$$

Fix $n=0$ for simplicity, so one of these points (red) is attained when $t=\dfrac12\csc^{-1}(2a)+\dfrac\pi4$, and we attain the same point again (blue) in the next period of the curve when $t=-\dfrac12\csc^{-1}(2a)+\dfrac{11\pi}4$.

[image]

The $x$-coordinates of these points are identical, so we must have

$$x\left(\frac12\csc^{-1}(2a)+\frac\pi4\right) = x\left(-\frac12\csc^{-1}(2a)+\frac{11\pi}4\right) \\[2ex]
\implies \csc^{-1}(2a) + a \sin\left(\frac\pi2+\csc^{-1}(2a)\right) = \frac{5\pi}2 + a \sin\left(\frac{11\pi}2-\csc^{-1}(2a)\right) \\
\implies \csc^{-1}(2a) + 2 a \cos\left(\csc^{-1}(2a)\right) = \frac{5\pi}2 \\
\implies \csc^{-1}(2a) + \sqrt{4a^2-1} = \frac{5\pi}2$$

Solving for $a$ exactly seems [unlikely](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sqrt%284a%5E2-1%29+%2Barccsc%282a%29+%3D+5pi%2F2).

Comment: Amazing : the problem reduced to the second root of $\tan(x)=x$ with $x=\sqrt{4a^2-1}$